# executing a binary java file using Runtime.exec on server

Tags: java, jsp, cmd

i am trying to build an online java compiler , written in jsp , where server end accepts uploaded code from clients , compile them and then run the codes and finally prints the output to the user to html forms.
i wrote a code that creates a temporary java file (temp.java) contains the code from client , then compile it , creating the (temp.class) file   , 
the problem is in the final step when i try to execute the file , it runs fine when i use the local machine cmd :

```
java temp
```

but when i call the command on the server using the java runTime like this :

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java testing/temp");
```

the output is :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class temp
```

the problem is  , the runtime cant find the binary file..
what is the path then ?
the compiler is in a package that contains the java files , while the clients binary files are createdand stored  in a folder (testing) in build/web ..

Comment: This sounds like a fantastically bad idea. I give you ten minutes before you're pwned.

Comment: okay then how a good idea can work here ?
i have no idea about how online compilers work  ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to provide full path to your class. I think it should help.

Comment: i tried to get the full path using this :
    
**String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/testing");**

but it didnt work either ..